# SQL data - encode json in particular format

Tags: php, sql, json, ms-access-2003

I have php code that I'm using along with sql to get results from a DB base on EA number and ID number to graph them.

```
<?php   
            $sql=
                ("SELECT D as y,Total as a,PoweredOn as b 
                FROM MasterUsageTable 
                WHERE ID IN 
                (SELECT ID FROM MasterUsageTable
                WHERE EA_Number = '$valueEA' AND D BETWEEN #$valueSDate# AND #$valueEDate#)");

            $rs = odbc_exec($con, $sqlVMs);
            if (!$rs) {
                exit("Enter EA!");
            }
            $data = array();
                while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)){
                    $data[] = $row;
                }           

            echo json_encode($data);
        ?>
```

At the moment the way I'm getting my results after the json encode is like this:

> [{"y":"2015-03-26","a":"16","b":"14"},{"y":"2015-03-26
>   ","a":"59","b":"12"},{"y":"2015-03-26
>   ","a":"21","b":"5"},{"y":"2015-03-26
>   ","a":"35","b":"12"},{"y":"2015-03-26 ","a":"17","b":"2"}]

I was hoping there was some way of separating them like so:

> [{"y":"2015-03-26","a":"16","b":"14"},{"y":"2015-03-26
>   ","a":"59","b":"12"},{"y":"2015-03-26
>   ","a":"21","b":"5"}],[{"y":"2015-03-26
>   ","a":"35","b":"12"},{"y":"2015-03-26 ","a":"17","b":"2"}]

So that it’s multiple arrays of data based on which ID it is. Hope that makes sense, thanks

Comment: Your SQL returns a single "set" so there is no way to have it encode as you want - the information just isn't there. It may be possible to add ID to the query and then transform the json, but I don't have enough skill to help with that. Check the related questions - there may be one about embedding maps within maps.

Comment: Incidentally, you can remove the `WHERE ID IN 
                (SELECT ID FROM MasterUsageTable` part from your SQL and it will work the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it would be to use an outer loop by ID and an inner loop to retrieve the values for each ID value, something like this:

```php
<?php
// test data
$valueSDate = "2015-03-26";
$valueEDate = "2015-03-26";
$valueEA = "EA1";

$allData = array();
$con = odbc_connect(
        "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" .
        "Dbq=C:\\Users\\Public\\Database1.accdb;",
        "Admin", "");
$rs1 = odbc_exec($con, 
        "SELECT DISTINCT ID " .
        "FROM MasterUsageTable " .
        "WHERE EA_Number = '$valueEA' " .
            "AND D BETWEEN #$valueSDate# AND #$valueEDate#");
while ($row1 = odbc_fetch_array($rs1)) {
    $id = $row1["ID"];
    $rs2 = odbc_exec($con, 
            "SELECT D as y,Total as a,PoweredOn as b " .
            "FROM MasterUsageTable " .
            "WHERE ID = $id AND EA_Number = '$valueEA' " .
                "AND D BETWEEN #$valueSDate# AND #$valueEDate#");
    $idData = array();
    while ($row2 = odbc_fetch_array($rs2)) {
        $idData[] = $row2;
    }
    $allData[] = $idData;
}

echo json_encode($allData);
```

Comment: Thanks man, I somehow managed to figure it out after I asked this but I trust your solution works too!